# Convert XmlDocument to FileInfo

Tags: c#, serialization, xmldocument, fileinfo

I have a web service which returns a string representing an Xml file. The string is properly formed xml. 
I need to create FileInfo object from the string so that I can deserialize it.

I don't have the file path or even if i do thats of no use as it is a disconnected server.

I can convert string to XmlDocument by -

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(MyString);
```

How do I get FileInfo so that I can deserialize it? Please help.

---

Solution:

Thanks for your replies. I created XmlReader from the string returned by the service and used XmlSerializer.Deserialize to get the object I needed.

```
using (XmlReader tr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(mystring)))
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(<T>), extraTypes);
  <T> serizalizedForm =  serializer.Deserialize(tr) as <T>;
}
```

Comment: Added C# tag. If that isn't relevant, say so in the comments.

Comment: I'm really not sure where `FileInfo` becomes relevant in this...?

Comment: Marc, you were right. I didn't need FileInfo. I updated my post with the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a class that represents the structure of the xml to deserialize it into.   using xsd.exe and an instance of the xml that is returned you can create this class ( /c switch) and then use xmlserializer to deserialize.

[Here is an example of a method that deserializes the xml (**Update: This link is broken**)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200204000600/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/paulwhitblog/archive/2007/07/20/114076.aspx)

Comment: Jason, the linked helped me. Thanks.